# Do I need to create All folders for layout for all screen sizes?

Tags: android-layout

I am creating an app targeting all `screen sizes` and `densities`.
Do I need To put my layout in all folders named-

```
layout-large-port
layout-large-land
layout-small-port
layout-small-land
layout-normal-port
layout-normal-land
layout-xlarge-port
layout-xlarge-land
```

or there is any other standard way?

Also, what about the text size in each layout? If I need large font in xlarge size an small font in small size, then how to adjust same?

Answer (score 0):

Android tries to find the most specific match when looking for a resource. If none is found, it will try less and less specific until a match is found. So for example, if you're running on xlarge-land, then it will look for any resource first in `layout-xlarge-land`, then in `layout-xlarge` or `layout-land` (not sure which order) and finally in the unqualified `layout`. This means if you design your layout XML's in such a way that they're generic, you don't have to provide every possible bucket.

The [Supporting Different Screen Sizes](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html) section of the Android Developer Training goes into this in detail. It also includes a useful "layout alias" trick that you can use to avoid copy-paste coding.

Comment: what about the text size in each layout?  If I need large font in xlarge size an small font in small size, then how to adjust same?

Comment: you can check the device whether it is large or xlarge or small or phone sized and then set font programatically

Comment: It's easiest to use multiple values folders (`values`, `values-small`, `values-xlarge`) and put [dimensions resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Dimension) in there. You don't have to set the text size programmatically.